# How to convert enclosed double quotes to single quotes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I am experiencing a very strange behavior of Javascript.

I get the data object in the form of a string from the server as shown below,

```
"{'id':1234, 'name'}"
```

When I try to parse this data using JSON.parse() it throws

```
JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

However changing the data to `'{"id":1234, "name"}'` will work.

But my question is how do I transform:

```
"{'id':1234, 'name'}" to '{"id":1234, "name"}'
```

in the javascript end? (I dont want to change any thing in the server).

Comment: *"However changing the data to '{"id":1234, "name"}' will work"*. No, it doesn't.

Comment: `{"id":1234, "name"}` is not valid either, you need a value `{"id":1234, "name":"somename"}`

Comment: Is the server supposed to be generating JSON?  If so, don't you think it would be beneficial to update the server?

Comment: Your JSON code is invalid. You need to fix that, And in JSON the correct character is double quotes. Make the one who produced the invalid code fix it,

Comment: You need the server code to be fixed, because it probably have many more bugs. for example what happens if the string has a "single quote"? `{'test':'It doesn't work'}`

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to replace the character(') as global, here the code:

```js
var yourString = "{'id':1234, 'name'}";
yourString = yourString.replace(/\'/g, '"');
console.log(yourString);
```

And in vice versa:

```js
var yourString = '"{\'id\':1234, \'name\'}"';
    yourString = yourString.replace(/\'/g, '"');
    yourString = yourString.replace(/\"/g, "'");
    console.log(yourString);
```

Here other example with mixed characters( " and ' ):

```js
    var yourString = "{\"id':1234, 'name'}";
    yourString = yourString.replace(/\'/g, '"');
    console.log(yourString); // Automatically skips the right character(")
```

Comment: Except that will not make the string a valid JSON string due to the missing name value

Comment: Of course, JSON.parse(); Can't recognize the character('), only can use("), but you can use my filter to convert  the char(') to ("), and JSON.parse() will works...

Comment: What about strings within that _"JSON"_ that have single-quotes? This is too optimistic

Comment: @BennyWood - the result is still not valid because the second attribute is missing a value

Comment: Absolutly nothing, the filter automatically skip the right character look this example:

Comment: var yourString = "{\"id':1234, 'name'}"; yourString = yourString.replace(/\'/g, '"'); console.log(yourString);

Comment: @BennyWood What about `{'test':'It doesn't work'}` ?

Comment: Im creating a new method for get a solution for: "{'test':'It doesn't work'}"

Comment: Sorry, Can't work in "{'test':'It doesn't work'}", no regex found for do that..

Comment: @BennyWood.. with the above code i am still not able to extract the id and name from the string...